# Can you do gamerule keepInvintory true on a PC relm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have tried many times on my realm to set keepinvintory to true using a command block and changing the capitalization  but it wont work. Whenever I /kill I still lose my stuff. Is it possible to do on a realm? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, what's the command you're using?

Comment: /gamerule keepInvintory true

Comment: From the multiple times you have typed it, it might be a simple typo. "Inventory" only has 1 "i". `/gamerule KeepInventory true`. And yes, the capitalisation is important.

Comment: I am reiterating the point Ben made.  You have misspelled `keepInventory` in your title, in your question, and in your command comment.

Answer (score 3):

Late to comment, but for anyone else that ends up on this thread...

1.13 Aquatic Update now has tab auto-completion for commands. So, you just have to type enough to isolate the command you want then hit the tab key to auto-complete it and move to the next part you need to fill in.

For `/gamerule keepinventory true` ...

`/gamer` (tab) `ke` (tab) `t` (tab)`

`/gamer` is enough to isolate `/gamerule`, so tab will auto-complete that
`ke` is enough to isolate `keepinventory` in the gamerule arguments
`t` is enough to isolate `true` out of true/false

Of all the updates in 1.13, I think the auto-completion intellisense is the most useful.

Comment: Great first answer, welcome to the site. I have added a bit of formatting to your answer to make it easier to read. If you would like to learn more about the formatting for futre questions you can checkout the [help page here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as long as you are the owner of the Realm or have operator permissions.

Try /gamerule keepInventory true

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I am the creator of the relm

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you spelled it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you spell it the right way, including capitalization.

So the good way of spelling it would be the following:

```
/gamerule keepInventory true
```